# Check for array - is value contained in another array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'd like to return a boolean for each value in array `A` that indicates whether it's in array `B`. This should be a standard procedure I guess, but I can't find any information on how to do it. My attempt is below:

```
A = ['User0','User1','User2','User3','User4','User0','User1','User2','User3'
     'User4','User0','User1','User2','User3','User4','User0','User1','User2'
     'User3','User4','User0','User1','User2','User3','User4','User0','User1'
     'User2','User3','User4','User0','User1']
B = ['User3', 'User2', 'User4']
contained = (A in B)
```

However, I get the error:

```
ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape
```

I'm using numpy so any solution using numpy or standard Python would be preferred.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use [`in1d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html) I believe -

```
np.in1d(A,B)
```

Answer (score 6):

For testing it without using `numpy`, try:

```
contained = [a in B for a in A]
```

result:

```
[False, False, True, True, True, False, False, True, False, False,
 False, True, True, True, False, False, False, True, False, False,
 True, True, True, False, False, True, True, False, False]
```

Comment: For this small example, this list comprehension is considerably faster than `np.in1d`.